# Mobile app automation for angular application

Tags: protractor, appium

I have successfully set up protractor appium tests to run on (connected devices )Mobile iOS and Android browser.

We have a mobile app that is slightly different than the web app. I would like to automate that as well. But understand protractor appium doesn't support native app yet. Is there any other tool which will allow us to automate angular apps besides appium? Please advise.

Thanks,